# How to download and record videos using Canon EDSDK in C#?

Tags: c#, edsdk, canon-sdk

I am trying to create an application that will grab photos and videos from Canon cameras.
I have found a way to take photos and to download them on PC, but i didn't find the  possibility to download videos.

Is there a way to record and  download videos using Canon EDSDK in C#?

Comment: A quick search yields this - have you tried ? - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688276/Canon-EDSDK-Tutorial-in-Csharp

Answer (score 4):

There is a good explanation how to do it here: http://www.magora-systems.com/using-canon-edsdk-in-net-development/